# Start Activity from WorkManager API Level 29+

Tags: android, kotlin, service, policy, android-workmanager

We can't start activity from Work Manager according to the new [Restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) If App doesn't meet the requirements. All i want is to start activity from Work Manager even application is killed or no longer visible after some specific time. I do not want to run the App in foreground. Is there anyway, I can achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have in house App or for testing, You can use this approach.

Add this permission in Menifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Also go to the App info settings

```
Setting -> Advanced -> Display over other apps
```

Allow this permission for this app. Now run the app, This will be able to start the activity from background.

But, I recommend to show notification and open the screen on tap notification.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't start activities from background since it interrupts user's work.

If you want to open your app from work manager, you'll have to use notifications instead and set the notification tap action to open your specific activity using pending intents.
[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#click) is a guide on how to create a notification in android.

Additionally, if your app needs to do something urgently, you can create a high priority notification, details [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive#create-high-priority-notification)

Comment: I want to show the screen without tapping on notification.

Comment: That isn't possible. You can though create a full screen intent but that too will be decided by the android system whether to launch it or just display a heads up notification

Comment: its sad i cant do this :(

Comment: They have to be different. Channel_ID is a constant for a particular notification channel. Notification_ID on the other hand is related to a particular notification. It's like an identifier to identify a notification so that you can cancel it later if you want .